# Is there a word such as "history" that refers to a personal past without traditional "historical" connotations?

Tags: synonyms, history

I am creating an application that gives information about old buildings. The app has two modes: History mode and *Requested Word* mode.

History mode would include buildings that are thought of in the typical historical context, e.g., Monticello or the White House.

The other mode would provide details about everyday buildings, e.g., my house. This mode would give information about a building's past in a way similar to how Zillow provides details about a house's previous sale prices and upgrades but without implying any sort of historical relevance.

Is there a reader-friendly word that means "history" or "past" but excludes topics one would cover in a history lesson?

Comment: Perhaps *culture* and *history* fit better. Alternatively, if you accept that history without commentary is just statistics, consider *history* and *stats*.

Comment: Are you looking for something like “well-known” and “Ordinary”  or “Famous” and “Mundane”??

Comment: Would specifics or specifications work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like **background**, and had initially thought of it myself. However, I have an alternate suggestion.

[**Narrative**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narrative):

> something that is narrated : STORY, ACCOUNT · He is writing a detailed narrative of his life on the island.

In other words, while the block on which a house is situated might have historical significance, the events that took place in the house, as it had different owners, is more of a mundane *narrative* (without historical import).

Certain events that might otherwise be part of its narrative could be part of its history instead—if they are significant enough. For instance, somebody being shot in the house and having it make headline news could be considered history. Whereas a child breaking a window that is then repaired would only be part of the narrative.

Answer (score 3):

How about **background** or **backstory**?

(History actually seems the most appropriate term to me, but I can understand your desire to differentiate the two kinds of "history".)

Answer (score 1):

If the goal were "labels" not a word that stands alone outside of a context, you could try '**records**' or '**log**' - possibly '**ledger**' or '**journal**'

An associated word would be required for these to make sense.. they need to "belong" to something.

**log** would be my first choice.

'structure log' , or 'character log'  .. etc ?

Note - this does not answer the "title" question but is more a ~label~ alternative for "historical mode" vs "log mode" .

> OP question outakes:
>
> **This mode would give information** about a building's past in a way similar to how Zillow provides details about a house's previous sale prices and upgrades but **without implying any sort of historical relevance**.
>
> Is there a reader-friendly word that means "history" or "past" but excludes topics one would cover in a history lesson?

Like

5th Regiment History

- participated in The Battle of the Bulge
- capture of Berlin

5th Regiment Log

- added 25 recruits
- lost 5 soldiers
- marched 250 miles

The labels would still be somewhat arbitrary and specific to a use-case context, but I believe these labels would an understandable convention within that context.